# CrudRepository interface - bean not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using CrudRepository like this

```
@Repository
public interface Reports extends CrudRepository<Report, UUID> {

}
```

when I'm trying to inject `Reports` repository to service like this

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
class ReportsService {

    private final Reports reports;

// ...
}
```

I'm getting

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in ReportsService required a bean of type 'Reports' that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type Reports in your configuration.
```

my gradle dependencies file looks like this

```
    implementation(
            'org.flywaydb:flyway-core',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.3.3',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5',
            'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1',
            'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    )
```

what could be configured wrong?

Comment: Is your interface annotated with @Repository ?

Comment: @LuisIñesta I added it now with no effect

Comment: Do you have `@ComponentScan` or `@EnableAutoconfiguration` somewhere? Try adding `@Import(Reports.class)` on top of `ReportsService`

Comment: That annotation is not required for Spring Data interfaces. The problem is _most likely_ that you have several Spring Data implementations included in your project and thus will need to specify a repository base type (such as `JpaRepository`). I doubt you need all the dependencies and can remove MongoDB and JDBC.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- that's most likely the reason. What if I need postgresql (`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`) and mongodb together?

Comment: If that's the case, then you simply have to be specific and extend `JpaRepository` and `MongoRepository` instead of being general and extending `CrudRepository`.

Comment: Yes, but I still need `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-data-mongodb` to include together, and apparently these two dependencies are causing the problem.

Comment: Also, adding `@EnableMongoRepositories` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` didnt help, I'm getting `Parameter 0 of constructor ReportsService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the solution was to get rid of `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb` and use something different instead, in my case I used mongodb Morphia.